# Create PDF in memory instead of physical file

Tags: c#, itext

How do one create PDF in memorystream instead of physical file using itextsharp.

The code below is creating actual pdf file.

Instead how can I create a byte[] and store it in the byte[] so that I can return it through a function

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35);
PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("c:\\Test11.pdf", FileMode.Create));
doc.Open();//Open Document to write
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("This is my first line using Paragraph.");
Phrase pharse = new Phrase("This is my second line using Pharse.");
Chunk chunk = new Chunk(" This is my third line using Chunk.");

doc.Add(paragraph);

doc.Add(pharse);

doc.Add(chunk);
doc.Close(); //Close document
```

Comment: Encrypted PDF using memory stream, we can refer this at, https://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Create-Password-Protected-Secured-PDF-using-iTextSharp-in-ASPNet.aspx

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Switch the filestream with a memorystream.

```
MemoryStream memStream = new MemoryStream();
PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, memStream);
...
return memStream.ToArray();
```

Comment: How do you get the contents of memStream to show in a PDF reader without creating a file?

Answer (score 26):

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10, 10, 42, 35);

byte[] pdfBytes;
using(var mem = new MemoryStream())
{
    using(PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, mem)) 
    {
        doc.Open();//Open Document to write
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("This is my first line using Paragraph.");
        Phrase pharse = new Phrase("This is my second line using Pharse.");
        Chunk chunk = new Chunk(" This is my third line using Chunk.");

        doc.Add(paragraph);

        doc.Add(pharse);

        doc.Add(chunk); 
    }
    pdfBytes = mem.ToArray();
}
```

Comment: PdfWriter does not implement IDisposable so you cannot use it in a using statement. Maybe this is just in the version I am using though (5.0.5) as I know there have been some class changes from version 4

Comment: @musefan, yes, in 5.0.5 that is the case. In the current version, 5.5, `PdfWriter` extends `DocWriter` which implements `IDocListener` which extends `IDisposable`.  I don't know exactly when `IDisposable` was added to `IDocListener` but it was some time after 5.0.5 and before 5.5.0.

Answer (score 21):

I've never used iTextPDF before but it sounded interesting so I took upon the challenge and did some research on my own. Here's how to stream the PDF document via memory.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ShowPdf(CreatePDF2());
}

private byte[] CreatePDF2()
{
    Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER, 50, 50, 50, 50);

    using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
    {
        PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, output);
        doc.Open();

        Paragraph header = new Paragraph("My Document") {Alignment = Element.ALIGN_CENTER};
        Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph("Testing the iText pdf.");
        Phrase phrase = new Phrase("This is a phrase but testing some formatting also. \nNew line here.");
        Chunk chunk = new Chunk("This is a chunk.");

        doc.Add(header);
        doc.Add(paragraph);
        doc.Add(phrase);
        doc.Add(chunk);

        doc.Close();
        return output.ToArray();
    }

}

private void ShowPdf(byte[] strS)
{
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.ClearHeaders();
    Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
    Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + DateTime.Now);

    Response.BinaryWrite(strS);
    Response.End();
    Response.Flush();
    Response.Clear();
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Where your code has `new FileStream`, pass in a `MemoryStream` you've already created. (Don't just create it inline in the call to `PdfWriter.GetInstance` - you'll want to be able to refer to it later.)

Then call [`ToArray()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx) on the `MemoryStream` when you've finished writing to it to get a `byte[]`:

```
using (MemoryStream output = new MemoryStream())
{
    PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, output);

    // Write to document
    // ...
    return output.ToArray();
}
```

I haven't used iTextSharp, but I *suspect* some of these types implement `IDisposable` - in which case you should be creating them in `using` statements too.