# Method to convert HTML from database to renderable format in a PDF with iTextSharp

Tags: c#, pdf, asp.net-web-api, itext, xmlworker

```
var paper =  _repo.VeryLatestPaper().Result;
List list = new List(List.ORDERED);
paper.Questions.ForEach(q => list.Add(q.Message));

var doc1 = new Document(); 

string path = "B:\\Test\\PDF";
PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc1, new FileStream(path + "/Doc1.pdf", FileMode.Create));
writer.PageEvent = new PDFWriterEvents("This is a Test");


doc1.Open();

//new XMLParser().Parse(new StringReader(text));

//XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc1, new StringReader(text));

doc1.Add(list);

doc1.Close();
```

I am using the above code with the **latest itextsharp** to generate a pdf list. So far it's working very excellently, until when I want to convert each `itextsharp` list from html to at least plain text, or preferably formatted text with images if possible. Someone please assist me convert `q.Message` to pdf of plain text ready for rendering to pdf file with `XMLWorker` and this code here .

```
//new XMLParser().Parse(new StringReader(text));

//XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc1, new StringReader(text));
```

Please note that I am not getting the html from a file, it's from the database…

Comment: You can use other kinds of streams than just filestreams. You can load the HTML in memory an pass a MemoryStream, for instance, or maybe you can get a stream representation from the database field directly.  [Related question about using `PdfWriter.GetInstance` with a memory stream](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815761/create-pdf-in-memory-instead-of-physical-file).

Comment: hi Golez, let me heck it out...

Answer (score -1):

It has ability to convert HTML file in to pdf.

It has already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25164258/231316). I am making some chages here.

Required namespace for conversions are:

```
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
```

and for conversion and download file :

```
//Create a byte array that will eventually hold our final PDF
            Byte[] bytes;

            //Boilerplate iTextSharp setup here
            //Create a stream that we can write to, in this case a MemoryStream
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {

                //Create an iTextSharp Document which is an abstraction of a PDF but **NOT** a PDF
                using (var doc = new Document())
                {

                    //Create a writer that's bound to our PDF abstraction and our stream
                    using (var writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, ms))

                    {

                        //Open the document for writing
                        doc.Open();


                        string finalHtml = string.Empty;
                       // read your html by database or from a html file here and store it into finalHtml e.g. a string



                        //XMLWorker also reads from a TextReader and not directly from a string
                        using (var srHtml = new StringReader(finalHtml))
                        {

                            //Parse the HTML
                            iTextSharp.tool.xml.XMLWorkerHelper.GetInstance().ParseXHtml(writer, doc, srHtml);
                        }



                        doc.Close();
                    }
                }

                //After all of the PDF "stuff" above is done and closed but **before** we
                //close the MemoryStream, grab all of the active bytes from the stream
                bytes = ms.ToArray();
            }





        //clear the response
            Response.Clear();
            MemoryStream mstream = new MemoryStream(bytes);
        //define response content type
            Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
        //give the name of file of pdf and add in to header
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=invoice.pdf");
            Response.Buffer = true;
            mstream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream);
            Response.End();
```

Try to put all css inline

Comment: Since you didn't make any changes to the code except removing a little bit this would probably be better as a comment that points to the [original answer that this was copied from](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25164258/231316)

Comment: Ok @Chris Hass,  will take care of that things now onwards. ☺. I had only added that response header as a pdf.