# Create PDF with iTextSharp without saving the file

Tags: c#, itext

I am using Visual Studio 2013, c# Windows Application, iTextSharp:

I can easily create/save a pdf file and write to it but is there a way to just use a pdf file and write to it without first saving it?  I don't want to be creating a temporary pdf file every-time someone runs a report.  Thanks in Advance !!

```
Document doc = new Document(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.LETTER, 10,10,42,35);

PdfWriter wri = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream("Test.pdf", 
FileMode.Create));

doc.Open();

\\\\ Then I do a bunch of stuff, then do a close


doc.Close();
```

Comment: *Write to it, without saving*?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Create PDF in memory instead of physical file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2815761/create-pdf-in-memory-instead-of-physical-file)

Comment: I am just guessing, but are you creating a web application? And do you want to offer the pdf as a download, without saving it to disk?

Comment: No, not web application, windows/desktop application

Answer (score -2):

You can use a MemoryMappedFile and write to it and it is not disk based.

```
using (MemoryMappedFile mmf = MemoryMappedFile.CreateNew("INMEMORYPDF.pdf", 1000000))
{
    PDFPageMargins margins = new PDFPageMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
    var document = new Document((_pageWidth > 540) ? PageSize.A4.Rotate() : PageSize.A4, margins.Left, margins.Right, margins.Top, margins.Bottom);
    using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
    {                       

        PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, stream);
        document.Open();
        //MODIFY DOCUMENT
        document.Close();                    
    }
    byte[] content;
    using (MemoryMappedViewStream stream = mmf.CreateViewStream())
    {
        BinaryReader rdr = new BinaryReader(stream);
        content = new byte[mmf.CreateViewStream().Length];
        rdr.Read(content, 0, (int)mmf.CreateViewStream().Length);
    }
    return content;            
}
```

Comment: Why use mmf when one can just use MemoryStream instead?

Comment: Well, for one a mmf can be shared between processes by passing handles or pointers.

Comment: For using the mmf you have to specify a maximum size. Choose this size too low, it will fail when the PDF needs more memory. Choose this size too high, it will fail when the address space in the process cannot provide enough continuous memory.

Comment: Still no valid reason this is invalid. I answered the OP's question and this code can be used in an application that needs large memory allocations that mimics a file. The file can the be used in inter-process communication.

Comment: @NineBerry - Thanks for the comment. You are correct. The way CreateNew is implemented an upfront size requirement is necessary.